how to add text annotations to text notes in a react nextjs 14 (app router) app
I am trying to build an app that allows users to comment on legal judgments. i have judgments and notes in my app. notes are made on the text of judgments. At the moment, when a user selects an area of the judgment text, an add note form collects the note and puts a span from the start to the end of the selected text.
this is working fine, for the first note added. after that the spans are misplaced. I can't see what im doing wrong. Can anyone suggest a better way to calculate how to place the spans for my notes?
This is my  judgmentDisplay component:
    'use client';

import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Judgment, Note, Selection } from '../../../types';

interface JudgmentDisplayProps {
  judgment: Judgment;
  notes: Note[];
  onTextSelect: (selection: Selection) => void;
  onNoteClick: (note: Note) => void;
}

export default function JudgmentDisplay({ judgment, notes, onTextSelect, onNoteClick }: JudgmentDisplayProps) {
  const contentRefs = useRef<{ [key: string]: HTMLDivElement | null }>({});

  const handleMouseUp = (event: React.MouseEvent, fieldName: string) => {
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    if (selection && selection.toString().length > 0) {
      const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
      const contentElement = contentRefs.current[fieldName];

      if (contentElement) {
        const preCaretRange = document.createRange();
        preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(contentElement);
        preCaretRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
        const start = preCaretRange.toString().length;
        const end = start + selection.toString().length;

        console.log(`Selected in ${fieldName}: "${selection.toString()}", start: ${start}, end: ${end}`);

        onTextSelect({
          text: selection.toString(),
          start,
          end,
          fieldName,
        });
      }
    }
  };

  const renderField = (fieldName: string, content: string) => {
    const fieldNotes = notes.filter(note => note.field_name === fieldName);
    const segments: React.ReactNode[] = [];
    let lastIndex = 0;

    fieldNotes.sort((a, b) => a.start_index - b.start_index).forEach(note => {
      if (note.start_index > lastIndex) {
        segments.push(content.slice(lastIndex, note.start_index));
      }
      segments.push(
        <React.Fragment key={note.id}>
          <span
            className="cursor-pointer text-blue-500"
            onClick={() => onNoteClick(note)}
          >
            *
          </span>
          <span className="bg-yellow-200">
            {content.slice(note.start_index, note.end_index)}
          </span>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
      lastIndex = note.end_index;
    });

    if (lastIndex < content.length) {
      segments.push(content.slice(lastIndex));
    }

    return (
      <div
        key={fieldName}
        ref={(el) => {
          if (el) {
            contentRefs.current[fieldName] = el;
          }
        }}
        className="mb-4"
      >
        <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-2">{fieldName}</h2>
        <div
          className="whitespace-pre-wrap"
          onMouseUp={(e) => handleMouseUp(e, fieldName)}
        >
          {segments}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.entries(judgment).map(([fieldName, content]) =>
        typeof content === 'string' ? renderField(fieldName, content) : null
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

this is my form handler:
'use client';

import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useUser } from '@clerk/nextjs';
import JudgmentSelector from './_components/judgments/judgmentSelector';
import JudgmentDisplay from './_components/judgments/judgmentDisplay';
import NoteForm from './_components/notes/noteForm';
import NotePanel from './_components/notes/notePanel';
import { Judgment, Note, Selection } from '../types';
import { fetchJudgments, fetchNotes, addNote, editNote, deleteNote } from './actions';

export default function Home() {
  const { user } = useUser();
  const [judgments, setJudgments] = useState<Judgment[]>([]);
  const [selectedJudgment, setSelectedJudgment] = useState<Judgment | null>(null);
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState<Note[]>([]);
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState<Selection | null>(null);
  const [isNoteFormOpen, setIsNoteFormOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedNote, setSelectedNote] = useState<Note | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      fetchJudgments().then(setJudgments);
    }
  }, [user]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedJudgment) {
      fetchNotes(selectedJudgment.id).then(setNotes);
    } else {
      setNotes([]);
    }
  }, [selectedJudgment]);

  const handleJudgmentSelect = (judgment: Judgment) => {
    setSelectedJudgment(judgment);
    setSelection(null);
    setIsNoteFormOpen(false);
    setSelectedNote(null);
  };

  const handleTextSelect = (newSelection: Selection) => {
    console.log(`Selected text: "${newSelection.text}", start: ${newSelection.start}, end: ${newSelection.end}, field: ${newSelection.fieldName}`);
    setSelection(newSelection);
    setIsNoteFormOpen(true);
  };

  const handleNoteSubmit = async (comment: string) => {
    if (selection && selectedJudgment) {
      try {
        console.log(`Creating note in ${selection.fieldName}: "${selection.text}" at ${selection.start}-${selection.end}`);
        const newNote = await addNote(comment, selection.start, selection.end, selectedJudgment.id, selection.fieldName);
        console.log('New note created:', newNote);
        setNotes(prevNotes => [...prevNotes, newNote]);
        setIsNoteFormOpen(false);
        setSelection(null);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error adding note:", error);
      }
    }
  };

  const handleNoteClick = useCallback((note: Note) => {
    console.log('Note clicked:', note);
    setSelectedNote(note);
  }, []);

  const handleNoteUpdate = async (updatedNote: Note) => {
    try {
      console.log('Updating note:', updatedNote);
      const result = await editNote(updatedNote.id, updatedNote.comment, updatedNote.judgment_id);
      console.log('Note updated:', result);
      setNotes(prevNotes => prevNotes.map(n => n.id === result.id ? result : n));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error updating note:", error);
    }
  };

  const handleNoteDelete = async (noteId: number) => {
    if (selectedJudgment) {
      try {
        console.log('Deleting note:', noteId);
        await deleteNote(noteId, selectedJudgment.id);
        console.log('Note deleted:', noteId);
        setNotes(prevNotes => prevNotes.filter(n => n.id !== noteId));
        setSelectedNote(null);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error deleting note:", error);
      }
    }
  };

  if (!user) {
    return <div>Please sign in to access this page.</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto p-4">
      <JudgmentSelector
        judgments={judgments}
        selectedJudgment={selectedJudgment}
        onSelect={handleJudgmentSelect}
      />
      {selectedJudgment && (
        <JudgmentDisplay
          judgment={selectedJudgment}
          notes={notes}
          onTextSelect={handleTextSelect}
          onNoteClick={handleNoteClick}
        />
      )}
      {isNoteFormOpen && selection && (
        <NoteForm
          selection={selection}
          onSubmit={handleNoteSubmit}
          onClose={() => {
            setIsNoteFormOpen(false);
            setSelection(null);
          }}
        />
      )}
      <NotePanel
        note={selectedNote}
        onClose={() => setSelectedNote(null)}
        onNoteUpdate={handleNoteUpdate}
        onNoteDelete={handleNoteDelete}
      />
    </div>
  );
}


 spans are misplaced. what do you mean here? can you  pls create minimal reproducble code sample for others to help you

It could be an error in calculating and keeping track of the text indices and rendering the notes inside the text. Here are a few possible improvements and suggestions to help resolve the issue:
Use range.startContainer and range.endContainer Directly
const handleMouseUp = (event: React.MouseEvent, fieldName: string) => {
 const selection = window.getSelection();
  if (selection && selection.toString().length > 0) {
    const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    const contentElement = contentRefs.current[fieldName];

    if (contentElement) {
      const startOffset = range.startOffset;
      const endOffset = range.endOffset;

      const startIndex = calculateOffset(contentElement, range.startContainer, startOffset);
      const endIndex = calculateOffset(contentElement, range.endContainer, endOffset);

      console.log(`Selected in ${fieldName}: "${selection.toString()}", start: ${startIndex}, end: ${endIndex}`);

      onTextSelect({
        text: selection.toString(),
        start: startIndex,
        end: endIndex,
        fieldName,
      });
    }
  }
};

const calculateOffset = (parent: Node, node: Node, offset: number) => {
  let charCount = 0;
  const traverseNodes = (current: Node) => {
    if (current === node) {
      charCount += offset;
      return;
    }
    if (current.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      charCount += current.textContent?.length || 0;
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < current.childNodes.length; i++) {
        traverseNodes(current.childNodes[i]);
      }
    }
  };
  traverseNodes(parent);
  return charCount;
};

Use document.createRange() and Range.getBoundingClientRect()
This helps to visualize and understand the selected text position:
const visualizeSelection = (range) => {
  const rects = range.getClientRects();
  for (let i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
    const rect = rects[i];
    const highlight = document.createElement('div');
    highlight.style.position = 'absolute';
    highlight.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.4)';
    highlight.style.left = `${rect.left + window.scrollX}px`;
    highlight.style.top = `${rect.top + window.scrollY}px`;
    highlight.style.width = `${rect.width}px`;
    highlight.style.height = `${rect.height}px`;
    document.body.appendChild(highlight);
  }
};

const handleMouseUp = (event: React.MouseEvent, fieldName: string) => {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  if (selection && selection.toString().length > 0) {
    const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    visualizeSelection(range);
    // ... code for handling selection
  }
};

Normalize Spans After Each Update
Ensure that spans are recalculated and properly ordered whenever new notes are added.
const normalizeSpans = (content, notes) => {
  notes.sort((a, b) => a.start_index - b.start_index);
  const segments = [];
  let lastIndex = 0;

  notes.forEach(note => {
    if (note.start_index > lastIndex) {
      segments.push(content.slice(lastIndex, note.start_index));
    }
    segments.push(
      <React.Fragment key={note.id}>
        <span className="cursor-pointer text-blue-500" onClick={() => onNoteClick(note)}>*</span>
        <span className="bg-yellow-200">{content.slice(note.start_index, note.end_index)}</span>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
    lastIndex = note.end_index;
  });

  if (lastIndex < content.length) {
    segments.push(content.slice(lastIndex));
  }

  return segments;
};

const renderField = (fieldName: string, content: string) => {
  const fieldNotes = notes.filter(note => note.field_name === fieldName);
  const segments = normalizeSpans(content, fieldNotes);

  return (
    <div
      key={fieldName}
      ref={(el) => {
        if (el) {
          contentRefs.current[fieldName] = el;
        }
      }}
      className="mb-4"
    >
      <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-2">{fieldName}</h2>
      <div
        className="whitespace-pre-wrap"
        onMouseUp={(e) => handleMouseUp(e, fieldName)}
      >
        {segments}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

Text-based Metadata for Managing Notes
Instead of relying on spans and direct DOM manipulations, use metadata to manage notes and render them dynamically.
const handleTextSelect = (newSelection: Selection) => {
  const updatedNotes = [
    ...notes,
    {
      id: new Date().getTime(), // or any unique ID generator
      text: newSelection.text,
      start_index: newSelection.start,
      end_index: newSelection.end,
      field_name: newSelection.fieldName,
    },
  ];
  setNotes(updatedNotes);
  setIsNoteFormOpen(true);
};

// Render notes using metadata
const renderField = (fieldName: string, content: string) => {
  const fieldNotes = notes.filter(note => note.field_name === fieldName);
  const segments = normalizeSpans(content, fieldNotes);

  return (
    <div
      key={fieldName}
      ref={(el) => {
        if (el) {
          contentRefs.current[fieldName] = el;
        }
      }}
      className="mb-4"
    >
      <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-2">{fieldName}</h2>
      <div
        className="whitespace-pre-wrap"
        onMouseUp={(e) => handleMouseUp(e, fieldName)}
      >
        {segments}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

Final component
'use client';

import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { Judgment, Note, Selection } from '../../../types';

interface JudgmentDisplayProps {
  judgment: Judgment;
  notes: Note[];
  onTextSelect: (selection: Selection) => void;
  onNoteClick: (note: Note) => void;
}

export default function JudgmentDisplay({ judgment, notes, onTextSelect, onNoteClick }: JudgmentDisplayProps) {
  const contentRefs = useRef<{ [key: string]: HTMLDivElement | null }>({});

  const handleMouseUp = (event: React.MouseEvent, fieldName: string) => {
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    if (selection && selection.toString().length > 0) {
      const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
      const contentElement = contentRefs.current[fieldName];

      if (contentElement) {
        const startOffset = range.startOffset;
        const endOffset = range.endOffset;

        const startIndex = calculateOffset(contentElement, range.startContainer, startOffset);
        const endIndex = calculateOffset(contentElement, range.endContainer, endOffset);

        console.log(`Selected in ${fieldName}: "${selection.toString()}", start: ${startIndex}, end: ${endIndex}`);

        onTextSelect({
          text: selection.toString(),
          start: startIndex,
          end: endIndex,
          fieldName,
        });
      }
    }
  };

  const calculateOffset = (parent: Node, node: Node, offset: number) => {
    let charCount = 0;
    const traverseNodes = (current: Node) => {
      if (current === node) {
        charCount += offset;
        return;
      }
      if (current.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        charCount += current.textContent?.length || 0;
      } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < current.childNodes.length; i++) {
          traverseNodes(current.childNodes[i]);
        }
      }
    };
    traverseNodes(parent);
    return charCount;
  };

  const normalizeSpans = (content: string, notes: Note[]) => {
    notes.sort((a, b) => a.start_index - b.start_index);
    const segments: React.ReactNode[] = [];
    let lastIndex = 0;

    notes.forEach(note => {
      if (note.start_index > lastIndex) {
        segments.push(content.slice(lastIndex, note.start_index));
      }
      segments.push(
        <React.Fragment key={note.id}>
          <span
            className="cursor-pointer text-blue-500"
            onClick={() => onNoteClick(note)}
          >
            *
          </span>
          <span className="bg-yellow-200">
            {content.slice(note.start_index, note.end_index)}
          </span>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
      lastIndex = note.end_index;
    });

    if (lastIndex < content.length) {
      segments.push(content.slice(lastIndex));
    }

    return segments;
  };

  const renderField = (fieldName: string, content: string) => {
    const fieldNotes = notes.filter(note => note.field_name === fieldName);
    const segments = normalizeSpans(content, fieldNotes);

    return (
      <div
        key={fieldName}
        ref={(el) => {
          if (el) {
            contentRefs.current[fieldName] = el;
          }
        }}
        className="mb-4"
      >
        <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-2">{fieldName}</h2>
        <div
          className="whitespace-pre-wrap"
          onMouseUp={(e) => handleMouseUp(e, fieldName)}
        >
          {segments}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.entries(judgment).map(([fieldName, content]) =>
        typeof content === 'string' ? renderField(fieldName, content) : null
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

